# How to connect domain with vps in GoDaddy

Tags: dns, vps

I am new to GoDaddy, and i can't access cPanel of my server.
When i Googled a little i find that i have to connect my vps and domain to access cPanel and i have no idea how.

> Your domain's DNS information must propagate before you can access cPanel with your domain name. If you cannot access the cPanel interface with your domain name, use your domain's IP address.

[GoDaddy help page](https://in.godaddy.com/help/access-cpanel-on-my-server-19412)

Clear steps appreciated, cause I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point your A record to your server IP address. If you are unsure, please just kindly contact your support team.